# Converting a non-deterministic context free grammar to deterministic

Tags: computability, context-free, formal-grammars, nondeterminism

I have the non-deterministic context free grammar $$I \to abcX | abdY$$
$$X \to X d | \epsilon$$ $$Y \to XX |I$$ and i want to convert it into a deterministic. I know that the rules $I \to abcX | abdY$ and $X \to X d | \epsilon$ are causing the grammar to be non-deterministic so i rewrite them as $$I \to abI', \ I' \to cX | dY $$ and $$X \to \epsilon X', \ X' \to dX' | \emptyset$$ respectively, however a hint in this exercise tells me that the rule $$Y \to XX| I$$ has also a problem (causes the grammar to be non-deterministic) however i can't see why this is the case, can you explain why there is a problem with this rule, and how can i fix it?

Comment: Both XX and I have the same terminal prefix, namely the empty one. So their being right hand sides of rules with Y on the left violates the dCFG definition. I do not know how to convert this.

Comment: thank for your comment, i don't understand this, don't the rules $I' \to cX|dX$ have the same problem then, since the empty terminal prefix appears in front of both $cX$ and $dY$.

Comment: I think only the entire terminal (till the first non-terminal) prefix counts. otherwise the empty prefix would be common to all possible right-hand sides and thus the defintition would be meaningless.